# Jenkins deploy war file to tomcat

Tags: jenkins

[jenkins war file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVQTW.png)

I am trying to upload war file. I don't see the  manager username and password and i am not able to view it. Can someone help me what i am missing.